# Dynamic creation of classes in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically create classes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780963/dynamically-create-classes-in-java)

I have a query regarding Reflection concept in Java.

I am trying to create a SAX XML parser in Java. What is required to be done is I need to create a new class containing the fields as per the XML and use the class while parsing.
But this method will be very much specific to the XML chosen.

What I am pondering about is, whether there is any way that I can write an XML (SAX) parser that works with every possible XML? i.e., I need to create a class with fields contained in the XML dynamically and use the same class for parsing the XML file.

I hope I could present my question clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: @galuano1 oh.. no, thanks for the idea.. I will try to work on it now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation before but my xml parser needed some configuration.
My approach was having: a) parsing engine,  b) configuration.

Configuration part builds around XPath expressions to be passed in thru properties.
These are static XPath expression and requires update if input xml message changes.

The parsing engine part executes those expressions to query xml element, attribute, etc for populating the java object.

**EDIT:**

For example, a given xml (simplified, no namespace):

```
<msg>
    <something>
        <somenode>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </somenode>
    </something>
</msg>
```

Code example: (simplified)

```
String myXpExpr = "//version/text()";  // make it .properties
Document xmlDocument = DocumentBulderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlInputStream);
XPath xpXPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpXPath.compile(myXpExpr);
resultObject = expr.evaluate(xmlDocument, returnTypeQName);
```

This would give you "1.0.0" as the resultObject.

Comment: OK.. were you able to work around with SAX XML parsing API or required to shift to JAXB or some other API?

Comment: I was using XPath expression.  No SAX, JAXB nor JIBX.

Comment: Answer updated with an example